# java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, sqlexception

I am using SQLite in my java application, I have create some tables in my database.
when I insert element into people table `(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE)`,
 I got the exception below :

`java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (column NAME is not unique)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:342)
    at org.sqlite.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:363)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeUpdate(PrepStmt.java:85)
    at epfl.lca1.spism.DesktopClient$1.run(Myclass.java:71)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)`

and my code is :

```
final PreparedStatement s;
    Connection db = openOrCreateDatabase();
    try {
        s = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO People"+
                                "(Name) VALUES"+ 
                                "(?)");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("A: %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getId());

            for (People p : Peoplearray) {
                try {
                    s.setString(1,p.toString());
                    s.executeUpdate(); // line 71
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

maybe some element insert two times, how can I ignore inserting existed one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) can be uses with a conflict resolution clause to specify what happens when you have a constraint violation.
This will just ignore any attempt to insert a duplicate value:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO People (Name) VALUES (?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Name` column is `unique` two entries/rows cannot have same Name value. So change your query to something like

```
INSERT INTO People(Name)
Select ? from dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
    FROM People
    WHERE Name= ?)
```

This will insert the entry only if entry with same name does not exist.

Just to clear the confusion `DUAL` is a special table that comes in most of the databases. You can read its [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table).

Comment: I try db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO people(Name)"+
         "Select Name from people"+
         "WHERE Name NOT EXISTS"+
            "(SELECT *"+
             "FROM people"+
             "WHERE Name= ?)"); but I get following exception :java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "EXISTS": syntax error)

Comment: `Select Name from dual` and not `Select Name from people`

Comment: Please refer to syntax in the answer. It is `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and not 'WHERE Name NOT EXISTS'.

Comment: I try that too, but I still get exception ! java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "EXISTS": syntax error)

Comment: Still its the syntax error. Do not concatenate put entire content in single line/String. Also I would advice run the query using command line or any other SQL UI tool are using just so that you would now query is working fine. Then you can work on your syntax in java.

Comment: They are not in single line, also I try to connect to my database with sqlite3.exe, but I have not succeeded yet!